# Can the Inverse Trigonometric functions be calculated without Look-Up Tables?

Tags: calculus

EDIT:A computer calculates it by closing in on the value of the angle after iterating (+/-pi)/(Some constant). A user posted a link to the CORDIC method wiki but I can't understand it still after a day.

I tested the series expansion with a bunch of angles and close in on the angle after very iterations of the series:

Here I used Excel's Trig functions to find Sin, cos, tan, csc, sec, & tan for ".6" Radians. Using the Y=sin(y), & X=cos(x), & m=tan(y/x) I close in on the value of ARCTAN(Y/X) quickly and reliably.
[image]

Original Question:
I was thinking of this problem:
Given a Unit Circle and a line from the origin through it's circumference at some point where the X value is known but not the Y value find the Y-value.

You can use the pythagorean theorem to find Y or you can use ARCCOS(x) to get the angle "A" and then solve sin(A) to get the Y-value.

So I was in Excel and the Inverse Trig functions aren't available functions in MS Excel. So I made a "Look-Up-Table" of the Cosine of Angles 0-90 down to the third decimal point.

This made me wonder if it was possible to calculate ARCSIN, ARCCOS, or ARCTAN using mathematical formulas and logic. I then figured MS Excel didn't have them as functions because that would require huge LUTs to be loaded into the memory every time Excel is opened as being accurate to the 3rd decimal takes tens of thousands of cells. So I figured they just don't allow those functions.

I then read on wikipedia that they can be derived but it didn't explain. Does anyone know if the inverse trig functons can be derived with a mathematical proof or are they simply "arcsin(y)=the angle that a ray from the origin must be in order for it to cross the Circumference of a circle at a right angle at a point with a y-value of "y""?

This seems electronic enough because waveforms, frequency, phase angle and Angular velocity come into play a lot with complex impedance.

Comment: What are [ACOS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/acos-function-cb73173f-d089-4582-afa1-76e5524b5d5b), ASIN, ATAN, and ATAN2 in Excel if not inverse trigonometric functions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Math.SE

Comment: This is a math question. Voting to close. Please note that excel DOES have inverse trig functions. ASIN, ACOS and two versions of inverse tangent, ATAN and ATAN2.

Comment: I know, but about the calculator, how else would it do it? I can't imagine any other way that a computer can take the x or y value of a point on a circles circumference and return it's angle. I'm gobsmacked and have been for years on this. (Inverse Trig Functions I use for Filter Capacitor sizing when rectifying AC to a steady ripple free DC, if I want 5% Ripple max that gives me my Y-value -Voltage- and I get the change in Timeusing Arcsin to get the angle in degrees, subtract the previous angle of Peak Voltage -90 degrees- for the equation C=I(dT/dV).

Comment: @DannySebahar Like Bimpelrekkie said, CORDIC. Look at the link they gave.

Comment: @hearth I understand how computer can solve non inverse trig functions as they have formulas that are based on π. Trigonometric functions are simple because it's just a circle and the function is equal to 2πr in a base π numbering system. Sine starts at 0 at 0°, Cosine at 1 @ 0°, tangent is the slope of the line intersecting the origin, cotangent is the slope of the tangent like at the point where the ray intersects the circumference, the secant is the point on the x-axis where the cotangent line intersects it and the cosecant is the point on the y-axis where the cotangent line intersects it.

Comment: computers use approximations that are accurate enough based on the infinite series. They do the same for the normal trig functions.